# Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/crossSpawn' exception React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, phpstorm, create-react-app

I downloaded the installer node-v10.6.0-x64 and create-react-app-master package for working on React Application. After creating React App project on PhpStorm, I had the exception like this:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/crossSpawn'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\ReactProjects\create-react-app-master\packages\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js:18:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

I tried writing to the terminal of PhpStorm:

```
npm install --save-dev react-dev-utils
```

but it doesn't help.

How to solve this?

Comment: What package and of what version do you indicate in PhpStorm while creating a new React App project? It should be create-react-app package.

Comment: @Oksana, package > create-react-app-master>package.json, after that i just  wrote npm run start

Comment: can you  clarify what you did exactly? Did you install `create-react-app` via `npm i create-react-app -g`, or just cloned/downloaded https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app repo? Also, can you check if the issue persist after deleting `node_modules` from your project and re-installing them with `npm i`?

Comment: @lena, dowloaded from github.com/facebook/create-react-app. unfortunately nmp i ... also didn't work

Comment: this is not a right way to install `create-react-app`; please install it globally via `npm i create-react-app -g` and specify a path to installed package in *New project* wizard

Comment: @lena , I did all that you adviced, now how to run react app? can't find package.json file

Comment: do you mean that there is no `package.json` in your project root folder after creating a new project via *New > Project... > React App*?

Comment: @lena, yeap there is no `package.json`

Comment: you must have done smth wrong.. please create a support ticket, attaching a video that shows all your steps plus idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

Comment: @lena okay.Thank youuu

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Delete node_modules folder and run "npm install" .  Hope this will work

Comment: Having the same issue with my team...not sure how this is the accepted answer.

Comment: You can also try deleting package-lock.json

Comment: This did not fix the problem. Deleting the whole folder and re-checking out the repository and running npm install again did solve the issue.

Comment: Worked for me...

Comment: Why does this work