# 'npm start' throwing an error right away, barely any code yet

Tags: npm, react-redux

I have no actual executable code added to any of the files yet, all of the code that exists has been put inside helper files which aren't even imported into `App.js` or `index.js` yet. I ran the following commands in the terminal to make sure npm is set up like I always have it...

```
npm install redux
npm install react-redux
npm install --save redux-thunk
```

Yet whenever I run `npm start` I get the following error message...

```
react-scripts start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/crossSpawn'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nlanese21/code/projects/game_projects/legend_of_cliches/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js:18:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! legend_of_cliches@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the legend_of_cliches@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nlanese21/.npm/_logs/2021-08-31T12_28_06_269Z-debug.log
```

I see that it's looking for `'react-dev-utils/crossSpawn'` but I have absolutely no idea where the hell that could be in my code, I know I definitely didn't type it out. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/crossSpawn' exception React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097461/cannot-find-module-react-dev-utils-crossspawn-exception-react-app)

Comment: Unfortunately no, deleting the node_modules folder was one of the first things I tried